# Insert and select parameters in a page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page with an insert text box and a select box. When i complete the form, i press a button that send me to another page. 
The code is this:

```
<form id="login-form">
<input id="user-name" type="text" maxlength="30" name="user[name]" placeholder="Enter a username" autofocus="autofocus"/>
<select id="meeting-id" name="meeting[id]">
  <% _.each(meetings, function(meeting) { %>
    <option value='<%= meeting.get("meetingID") %>'>
      <%= meeting.get("meetingName") %>
    </option>
  <% }); %>
</select>
```

Is it possible skip this page with a URL where i insert these parameters? How can I do?

Edit: i want know if i can obtain a URL where i pass these parameters instead insert the parameters in the form. Is it possible.

For example `http://www.submit.com/username="prove"&meeting="yes"`

Comment: Not very clear what you want to do.

Comment: Do you mean you want the form to submit its params to a different URL? You need to expand on your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I would like to replicate the event of the button press with a URL that contain the parameters. Is It possible?